# createCGImage:fromRect: takes too much memory on iPhone 4 (iOS 7)?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

In my app, I need to convert a `CIImage` object to `UIImage`, so I'm using the following code:

```
CIImage *holder = XXX
CGImageRef cgImage = NULL;
@autoreleasepool
{
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGRect extent = [holder extent];
    cgImage = [context createCGImage: holder fromRect:extent];
    holder = nil;
}
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:1.0 orientation:imgOrientation];
CFRelease(cgImage);
```

This code works perfectly on iPhone 4S and later devices like iPhone 5 and iPhone 5S, but when I test it on a iPhone 4 device running iOS 7, the line `cgImage = [context createCGImage: holder fromRect:extent];` shoots straight up to 270+MB memory usage and caused the app to stop due to memory pressure. And I've also tried the `[UIImage imageWithCIImage:]` method, but what I got is a blank image.

So what's the problem here, is it the device/os combination or some wired usage here?

FYI: the image i'm using is 1936x2592 which is the standard output of iPhone 4 camera app.

Comment: If it were me, I'd try to figure out why calling `[UIImage imageWithCIImage:]` returns an empty image. That's likely to be a lot less memory-intensive than making copies of it in different formats just to work around that problem.